# Making some placemarks visible with Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a KML file with multiple placemarks, example below:

```
   <Placemark>
   <name>00550M</name>
   <description></description>
   <styleUrl>#550M</styleUrl>
   <Polygon>
     <outerBoundaryIs>
       <LinearRing>
         <tessellate>1</tessellate>
         <coordinates>
          -019.2041,63.4130
          -013.2722,57.0138
          004.2309,52.4405
           001.1318,49.5607
          -021.0657,55.3650
          -019.2041,63.4130
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
     </outerBoundaryIs>
   </Polygon>
</Placemark>
```

Using the Earth plugin I can turn populate an array with the placemarks :

```
if ('getFeatures' in top.mykml) {  
var firstChild = top.mykml.getFeatures().getFirstChild();
while(firstChild !== null){                                      
    top.myObjects.push(firstChild);
    firstChild = firstChild.getNextSibling();        
  }    
}
```

and make them visible or not :

```
for (var i = 0; i <  aLen; i++){
  aName = top.myObjects[i].getName();          
  aFL = (aName.substring(2, 5));    
  if (aFL == '200'){
    top.myObjects[i].setVisibility(true);               
  } 
}
```

However, getFeatures isn't available in Maps, and

```
if ('featureData' in top.mykml)
```

returns false.

Is it possible to achive what I want to do, if so how. If not I guess each placemark will have to go in a single file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KmlLayer doesn't give you access to the objects on the map.

You have two options that I can think of:

1. import your KML into FusionTables and use queries to display or hide the Placemarks
2. use a third party KML parser like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) that render the KML using native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects and expose those so you can control them

[example using geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_simplePlacemark.kml)